# Symfony paths issues

Tags: php, symfony, path, controller

I'm currently working on a basic Symfony project to discover this Framework, my website identifies some French rap albums and gives infos about it, then I created 2 Controllers : "DefaultController" and "AlbumsController". In the fist one, I implements some functions to displays some music lyrics and I use path names for the links and it's well work but with the second Controller I do the exact same things and it's not working. (Sorry for bad English).
Attached -> The problematic code
DefaultController :

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Musique;
use App\Form\AlbumsType;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use App\Controller\AlbumsController;
use App\Repository\AlbumsRepository;
use App\Repository\MusiqueRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use App\Entity\Albums;


class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('index.html.twig', [
            'title' => 'Accueil',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/albums", name="albums")
     */
    public function albums()
    {
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Albums::class);

        $albums = $repo->findAll();

        return $this->render('albums/index.html.twig', [
            'albums' => $albums,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/musiques", name="musiques")
     */
    public function musiques()
    {
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Musique::class);

        $musiques = $repo->findAll();

        return $this->render('musiques.html.twig', [
            'title' => 'Liste des Musiques',
            '$musiques' => $musiques,
        ]);
    }


    /**
     * @Route("/musiques/{id}", requirements={"id": "[1-9]\d*"}, name="randMusique")
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function randomMusique()
    {
        $random = random_int(1, 100);
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Musique::class);

        $musique = $repo->find($random);

        return $this->render('randomMusique.html.twig', [
            'musique' => $musique,
        ]);
    }

}
```

AlbumsController :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Albums;
use App\Form\AlbumsType;
use App\Repository\AlbumsRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/albums")
 */
class AlbumsController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="albums_index", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(AlbumsRepository $albumsRepository): Response
    {
        return $this->render('albums/index.html.twig', [
            'albums' => $albumsRepository->findAll(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/new", name="album_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $album = new Albums();
        $form = $this->createForm(AlbumsType::class, $album);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($album);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('albums_index');
        }

        return $this->render('albums/new.html.twig', [
            'album' => $album,
            'formAlbum' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="albums_show", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function show(Albums $album): Response
    {
        return $this->render('albums/show.html.twig', [
            'album' => $album,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="albums_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, Albums $album): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(AlbumsType::class, $album);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('albums_index');
        }

        return $this->render('albums/edit.html.twig', [
            'album' => $album,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="albums_delete", methods={"DELETE"})
     */
    public function delete(Request $request, Albums $album): Response
    {
        if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete'.$album->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->remove($album);
            $entityManager->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('albums_index');
    }
}
```

base.html.twig :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Projet &mdash; PHP{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/darkly/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/style.css')}}">
    {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">France-Rap</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor03"
            aria-controls="navbarColor03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor03">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('index') }}">Accueil</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('albums') }}">Liste des Albums</a>
            </li>
            {#
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('musiques') }}">Liste des Musiques</a> // The path isn't working
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('randMusique') }}">Musique Aléatoire</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('album_new') }}">Créer un Album</a>
            </li>
            #}
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        {% block search %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</nav>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

This is the error : 
[Render error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZZGP.png)
Resultat of the command :
[php bin/console debug:router musiques](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dNkt.png)

Comment: Have you tried using the [command line tool to debug your routes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#debugging-routes)?

Comment: I did it and everything seems normal. e.g. : musiques                   ANY        ANY      ANY    /musiques

Comment: Can you edit your question with the result from `php bin/console debug:router musiques`?

Comment: Ok I'll do that, I'm brand new on this website ^^

Comment: Your route seems fine, so the error you're getting doesn't make too much sense to me. Maybe some caching issue? I'm not familiar enough with Symfony to tell, so hopefully someone else can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

In the secreen shot of the error i can see that your view is picked up from cache try runing follwing comand:

> php bin/console cache:clear

Comment: Try changing the name of your route.